# Make ConstraintLayout responsive in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am working on a UI, in which I have to take email and number from user, buttons should must be at bottom, after button, there is a footer too on bottom. I have to make it responsive. I am using scroll view for this purpose. I am stuck on a point.
I am using wrap_content as height for a view, and giving its top to bottom of upper view, and its bottom to top of lower view's top. On small screens, it is working fine, but due to these constraints, on large screens, it is in the centre of screen.
Please have a look on it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/footer"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_sample"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loginTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/icon_img"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/exo_light"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/charcol_blue"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_Desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/loginTxt"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/exo_regular"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Enter your credentials"
        android:textColor="@color/charcol_blue"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/loginTxt" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEditTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_Desc"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_input_shape"
        android:fontFamily="@font/exo_regular"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingStart="25dp"
        android:paddingEnd="25dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_Desc" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/phone_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/loginEditTextEmail">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_input_shape"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

        <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
            android:id="@+id/ccp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:ccp_autoDetectCountry="true"
            app:ccp_defaultPhoneCode="41" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText_carrierNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint=" Ph Number"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/ccp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ccp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ccp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo_regular"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginBtnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_round_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo_regular"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/divider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/orText"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/loginBtnSubmit"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/orText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/orText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/orText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo_regular"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="OR"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/loginBtnSubmit" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/divider"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/orText"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/orText"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/loginBtnSubmit"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/orText" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/guestContinue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_round_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/exo_regular"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/instruction_black_color"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/orText" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="@font/exo_regular"
        android:text="App "
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txt2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txt2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/txt2"
        android:textColor="@color/charcol_blue"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/exo_regular"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Footer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/footerImg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/footerImg"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/footerImg"
        android:textColor="@color/charcol_blue"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/footerImg"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/logout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am facing issue agains a constraint layout whose id is: "phone_layout"

[image]

If I will use its height as 0dp, it will works fine on large screens, but on small screens (when scroll view will be used to scroll screen), this layout will not be shown because of 0dp height.

I want this phone_layout to be below of email layout on every screen(small/large).

Comment: Set the vertical [bias](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#CenteringPositioning) of the view you want to shift.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved it by using app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"